# Surface view not displaying anything

Tags: android, graphics, surfaceview

Hey everyone I am a noob at android graphics and would appreciate some help on my game. For some reason my surface view is getting loaded but nothing is getting rendered(not much here so it should be simple) only a black background. Appreciate any help =D.

public class StartActivity extends Activity {

```
GameView gameView;

Bitmap player;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    //init our resources
  //  InitializeResources();


    gameView = new GameView(this);

    player = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.raw.inspector);

    setContentView(gameView);

}



public void InitializeResources(){



  // sprite = new SpriteClass(gameView,player);


}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void stop(){


}


public void pause(){


}





public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {


    Thread gamethread = null;

    SurfaceHolder surfaceholder;

    boolean canvasready = false;




    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        surfaceholder = getHolder();

    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(player,0,0,null);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // if the canvas is ready draw to it
        while(canvasready ==  true)
        {
            if(!surfaceholder.getSurface().isValid())
            {
                continue;
            }

            Canvas c = surfaceholder.lockCanvas();

            gameView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            c.drawBitmap(player,0,0,null);



            surfaceholder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

        }


    }

    public void Pause(){
        canvasready =  false;

        while(true)
        {
            try{
                //tries to stop the thread
                gamethread.join();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            break;

        }


        gamethread = null;

    }

    public void Resume(){
        canvasready =  true;
        gamethread  = new Thread(this);

        gamethread.start();

    }

    public void stop(){


    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing a couple of Callbacks

check out the Next Example

[SurfaceView Example with SurfaceHolder](http://cell0907.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/tutorial-for-drawing-in-android.html)

your class should implements SurfaceHolder.Callback and call the function

holder.addCallback(this) 
holder is the Surface holder